# Cant databind Radiobutton group with LongListSelector

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-phone-8

On my page i have a `LongListSelector` & `DatePicker` as shown below.

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Categories, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Name="llsCategories"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AllCategories}"/>

<toolkit:DatePicker Name="dpDate" Value="{Binding LastModifiedOn,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Here is how i have defined my DataTemplate for `LongListSelector`. Notice, the `GroupName` property

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AllCategories">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <RadioButton Content="{Binding CategoryName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsCategorySelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             GroupName="categoryList"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The datasource for LongListSelector `Categories` is an `IList<Category>` present in my Viewmodel which already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

This is how i databind.

In constructor of page:

```
this.DataContext = App.ViewModel
```

In App.xaml

```
private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;
 public static MainViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
                if (viewModel == null)
                    viewModel = new MainViewModel();

                return viewModel;
            }
        }
```

**Problem:** I selected one of the categories(radio button) presented in my LongListSelector and then when i am done with selecting datetime,the radio button which is ticked previously gets un-ticked. Why ?

**EDIT:**
Here is the [sample code](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5C8E6EB4112F51CE!1112). You will need VS 2012. Run the project. Select first or last radio button. Then Select the date. Observe that previously selected radio button is now unticked.

Comment: Can you show the code that assigns your page's DataContext to your model? Also tell us when this code executes i.e. in which method/event.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud Updated the OP as requested.

Comment: You talk about a checkbox, but I don't see one in your code.

Comment: @ChrisF oops...updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues. Your main binding issue is becuase the `IsCategorySelected` property is on  `MainViewModel` instead of `Category` (since you're binding the selected property of the `Category` not `MainViewModel`).

Additionally, I wouldn't constantly recreate the categories list in `MainViewModel.Categories`, rather initialize the list once in your constructor, something like:

```
public MainViewModel()
        {
            _categories = new List<Category>();
            Category c1 = new Category { CategoryName = "Hi" };
            Category c2 = new Category { CategoryName = "Hello" };
            Category c3 = new Category { CategoryName = "Howdy" };
            _categories = new List<Category>();
            _categories.Add(c1);
            _categories.Add(c2);
            _categories.Add(c3);
        }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is just a sample code to demonstrate the problem. ;)  I will make changes to my VM & will check if it works.